# Изменение ориентации экрана kv

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

У меня вопрос, как можно определить ориентацию экрана на kivy и использовать её в kv коде
(нашёл вроде инструкцию без kv кода и не понял, как применить в мой код)

И к примеру сделать так, чтоб при повороте экрана в калькуляторе добавлялись кнопки.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58709696/5909792

Comment: А как это можно примянить в kv коде?

Comment: https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/lang.html?highlight=binding#event-bindings смотреть в `on_size: my_callback()`, думаю аналогично можно сделать и в классе питона, что в kv будет описан

Comment: Что-то не получается, как не пробывал